After Mac wake up, all Displays are messed up
I have two 4k Displays and one Drawing tablet (Full HD) on my Intel Mac mini Sonoma.
When I leave the system, and it goes to sleep, after wake up, the Displays are all messed up:

1 4k Monitor doesn't start at all
1 4k monitor has now HD resolution
The Drawing Tablet has now inherited all windows and it's a total mess.

Is there any way to prevent this? I have to disable energy saving altogether from preventing it happening.

Assuming this is reproducible, meaning it happens every time you select sleep from the menu. I would start by unplugging various combinations (there are only 7 possible combinations with 3 monitors) to see if you can identify a pattern, i.e. which combinations work and which don't. Until you do that it's difficult to say, since it may be just one of your monitors which is the root cause of the issue.

So you're saying the issue is not the computer but one of the monitors. Okay, will investigate further. I focused on the computer.
